# str_replace interference

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert a two letter language abbreviations to full words using `str_replace`.
The problem I'm having is that they're affecting each other when echoed out.

```
$lang = str_replace("en", "English", $lang); 
$lang = str_replace("es", "Spanish", $lang);
$lang = str_replace("pt", "Portuguese", $lang); 
$lang = str_replace("fr", "French", $lang);
$lang = str_replace("de", "German", $lang);
$lang = str_replace("it", "Italian", $lang);
$lang = str_replace("pl", "Polish", $lang);
$lang = str_replace("ru", "Russian", $lang);
$lang = str_replace("sv", "Spanish (El Salvador)", $lang);
$lang = str_replace("ko", "Korean", $lang);
$lang = str_replace("zh", "Chinese", $lang);
$lang = str_replace("nl", "Dutch", $lang);
```

An example: when I echo out `en`, I get `EnglIcelandich`.

The list above is bigger but that is just a example. I have tried renaming the vars but with no luck.

Comment: what does $lang contain ? please post a small snippet

Comment: You are repeatedly doing a str_replace on each result.

Comment: @Wololo the $lang will be a two letter word. Example en for English

Comment: you are rewriting the $lang variable every time. How is it possible to have "en"..

Comment: +1 only because `EnglIcelandich` is kind of amusing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simple! Use [`strtr`](http://www.php.net/strtr) instead.

```
<?php
$replace = array(
    "en" => "English",
    "es" => "Spanish",
    "pt" => "Portuguese",
    "fr" => "French",
    "de" => "German",
    "it" => "Italian",
    "pl" => "Polish",
    "ru" => "Russian",
    "sv" => "Spanish (El Salvador)",
    "ko" => "Korean",
    "zh" => "Chinese",
    "nl" => "Dutch"
);

echo strtr("en it sv\n", $replace);
```

Comment: Oh, that's better. I always thought `strtr` only did single characters for some reason :P

Comment: It does _feel_ that way somehow. It's odd.

Comment: That's PHP for you, one function 2 uses :s

Comment: +1 for showing me a new string function I haven't heard of before.

Comment: This one I got to work right away and works well and now I understand what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do them all at once using `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$map = array(
    'en' => 'English',
    ...
);

$lang = preg_replace_callback('/' . implode('|', array_keys($map)) . '/', function($match) use ($map) {
    return $map[$match[0]];
}, $lang);
```

Oh, and if any of your strings ever have any special characters in them, you'll need to map `preg_quote` to your array's keys and pass the delimiter as its second argument.

Comment: You really don't need a regex for this. Also using a callback is slow.

Comment: -1 for using regex. +1 to normalise because I'm not that cruel. But you still get a metaphorical -1 for using regex when you didn't need to.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I promise I thought of *`strtr`* and discarded it when I thought I remembered it only did single characters! :)

Answer (score 1):

If `$lang` will always be a two character string, there is no need for search/replace at all, just use a lookup table like this:

```
$languages = array(
    'en'=>'English' 
    'es'=>'Spanish'
    'pt'=>'Portuguese' 
    'fr'=>'French'
    'de'=>'German'
    'it'=>'Italian'
    'pl'=>'Polish'
    'ru'=>'Russian'
    'sv'=>'Spanish (El Salvador)'
    'ko'=>'Korean'
    'zh'=>'Chinese'
    'nl'=>'Dutch'   
);
$lang = $languages[strtolower($lang)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you expect things like `ensppt` as an original value, just use a mimic'd look-up table:

```
$lang_lookup = array(
  'en' => 'English',
  'es' => 'Spanish',
  'pt' => 'Portuguese',
  // ...
);
$lang = array_key_exists($lang, $lang_lookup) ? $lang_lookup[$lang] : 'Unknown';
```

Alternatively (but slower) you could copy one string to the other:

```
$lang_lookup = array(
  'en'=>'English',
  'es'=>'Spanish',
  'pt'=>'Portuguese', 
  'fr'=>'French',
  'de'=>'German',
  'it'=>'Italian',
  'pl'=>'Polish',
  'ru'=>'Russian',
  'sv'=>'Spanish (El Salvador)',
  'ko'=>'Korean',
  'zh'=>'Chinese',
  'nl'=>'Dutch'   
);
$lang = 'es stands for Spanish';

$output = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($lang); $i++){
  $l = substr($lang, $i, 2);
  if (array_key_exists($l, $lang_lookup)){
    $output .= $lang_lookup[$l];
    $i++;
  } else {
    $output .= $lang[$i];
  }
}
echo $output; // "Spanish stands for Spanish"
```

Comment: @DanielO: Yea, because I use `in_array` over `array_key_exists`. try now.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only support to be one occurrence in the string, then just check which one exists first. Using an array as a lookup table.

```
$languages = array(
    'en'=>'English' 
    'es'=>'Spanish'
    'pt'=>'Portuguese' 
    'fr'=>'French'
    'de'=>'German'
    'it'=>'Italian'
    'pl'=>'Polish'
    'ru'=>'Russian'
    'sv'=>'Spanish (El Salvador)'
    'ko'=>'Korean'
    'zh'=>'Chinese'
    'nl'=>'Dutch'   
);

foreach($languages as $key=>$value)
{
    if(strpos($lang,$key) !== false)
    {
        $lang = str_replace($key,$value,$lang);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$entries = array(
    "en" => "English",
    "es" => "Spanish",
    "pt" => "Portuguese",
    "fr" => "French",
    "de" => "German",
    "it" => "Italian",
    "pl" => "Polish",
    "ru" => "Russian",
    "sv" => "Spanish (El Salvador)",
    "ko" => "Korean",
    "zh" => "Chinese",
    "nl" => "Dutch"
);
```

Using str_replace:

```
for ( $i = 0 ;  $i < $entries['count']; $i++ ) {
    foreach($entries[$i] as $key => $entrie) {
        if ( is_string($key) ) {
        $result = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $entrie[0], $result);
        }
    }

    $contact_data[] = $result;
}
```

Comment: Why are you surrounding the key with `{..}`? what is `$entries`? can you edit to clarify?

Comment: The result have records archived from LDAP tree the structure is different, str_replace Operation: Inside the if block, it uses str_replace to search for occurrences of { + $key + } within the $result variable (which presumably exists outside this code snippet). If found, it replaces them with the value of $entrie[0]. This means it's replacing placeholders like {key} in $result with values from the current $entrie array